# Socket server in Azure Container Instance flooded by unknown connections

Tags: c#, azure, sockets, azure-container-instances

I have published a simple C# socket server on Azure and log all incoming connections, recording their IP and port. There are no VNets, Load balancers etc., just an Azure subscription with a single resource group, a container instance and a container registry.

Right after the container instance starts, the socket server begins recording 2 internal IPs (10.92.0.25 and 10.92.0.26) opening sockets on different ports at a crazy rhythm, like every 15 seconds.

Assuming no one is maliciously targeting my infrastructure (it's a trial Azure account btw), what might be going on?

I haven't configured any of them, but ChatGPT says it can be Azure Monitor, Azure Log Analytics or Azure Network Watcher, can that be the reason?

If so, can I exclude my container instance from the resources those three services are monitoring?

Would that be bad?

Comment: It sounds like Azure is monitoring your host to make sure it's up and responding to heartbeats. I would personally ignore the heartbeat noise leave it to do its thing. I suspect its also not causing your socket server any issues?

Comment: @SimonHughes all true, thanks! Also, I was hoping to learn more about "Azure internals", so to speak :D

Comment: is it only one app, single instance?

Comment: this looks to me instances trying to sync with each other

Comment: Hi @MoHaidar, yes, just one instance of an app